# Approximation of an Exponential Correlation Matrix with a Constant Correlation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation

I am given with a $N \times N$ matrix

$$
 \begin{align*}
  A = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
  1           & \rho_{h}           & \ldots & \rho_{h}^{N - 1} \\
  \rho_{h}           & 1                & \ldots & \rho_{h}^{N - 2} \\
  \vdots           & \vdots           & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
  \rho_{h}^{N - 1} & \rho_{h}^{N - 2} & \ldots & 1
  \end{bmatrix},
 \end{align*}
$$

where $0 \leq \rho_h \leq 1$ and $N \geq 2$. I would like to approimate A with another $N \times N$ matrix given as:

$$
B=  \begin{bmatrix}
  1           & \rho           & \ldots & \rho \\
  \rho           & 1                & \ldots & \rho \\
  \vdots           & \vdots           & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
  \rho & \rho & \ldots & 1
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

This basically means, finding a relation between $\rho$ and $\rho_h$ such that $A \approx B$.

Any thoughts on, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you want a 1 in the lower right corners?

Comment: Yes... made correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the least squares method, that is, to find a $\rho \in [0,1]$ that minimizes
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N 2\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (\rho - \rho_h^j)^2;
$$
note that the sum sums for each $k$ a boomerang-shaped or edge-shaped part of the matrix that is basically a rectangle that starts in $c_{N,k}$, goes to $c_{k,k}$ and makes an edge there and continues to $c_{k,N}$, where $c_{k,k}$ is left out, where $C$ is an arbitrary matrix.

Moreover, whenever $\| \cdot \|$ is a matrix norm (submultiplicative or not), you can think about minimizing $\|A - B\|$ as a function of $\rho$. In the above example, the norm was just the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: The similar problem is addressed in [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6809388/). The snapshot from the paper is available at [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agk6EaQq5ujBwFSzIh7BdrKYLLSc).  The paper used the technique presented in [17, Section IV] which is available at [link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b7f9/0d6cc8f013a1b6e7c89127850d915b8cc6ee.pdf).  Just wondering, whether the approach you offered is different from or similar to this. Can you please have a look at the links and advise?